# JavaMail: msg.setSubject() won't accept second argument (encoding) in version 1.4.7, throws compile time error

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-mail

I have a Java SE 7 project that uses maven with dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
  <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Recently I noticed problems with sending mails - subjects that contained some special chars (specific to Polish language) weren't properly displayed.

I found few questions on SO with solution: **add second argument to your `setSubject()` method**, like this:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
String subject = "ĄŻĄŻŚśążćół";
msg.setSubject(subject, "utf-8");
```

Looks nice, but NetBeans warned me that there is no overloaded method for `setSubject()` that accept two arguments. I ignored that, thought that "it's just NetBeans, probably it's some kind of internal error", but I was wrong.

I ran `mvn clean install exec:java` from terminal, and I got:

```
error: method setSubject in class Message cannot be applied to given types;
```

What's wrong? Documentation says that this version (1.4.7) supports specifing encoding in subject, **every** answer I found relies on that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `setSubject(String subject, String charset)` is added to the `MimeMessage` class. I.e. it is not part of the `Message` class.

So, changing:

```
Message msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

to

```
MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
```

should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. According to the API documentation [online](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/) setSubjects only
   takes a String as parameter.
2. There would be no point in passing an
       additional encoding, because you already have a String.

Specifying encoding makes sense when converting between bytes and Strings. E.g. this String constructor (quoted from Oracle's Java API documentation):

```
String(byte[] bytes, int offset, int length, Charset charset)
```

> Constructs a new String by decoding the specified subarray of bytes
>   using the specified charset.

Here you already deliver a String (with non-ascii charaters), so having an encoding specified makes no sense.

Comment: That's true, but sometimes apps like gmail tend to lose proper encoding for message subject. That's why I want to add it. I used to send mails via PHP, back then I had to write subject like this: `"Subject: =?UTF-8?B?".base64_encode($subject)."?="`. I guess that second parameter in `setSubject()` does something very similar.